# ClickOnce won't update when hosted in IIS 10.0 - Application download did not succed

Tags: iis, clickonce, iis-10

I host ClickOnce application files under my IIS 10.0 (running on Windows 10), but when I publish a new update and try to update the application on my PC I get the error bellow. Details are shown below, but we can see "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." and "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

MIME type are configured on my IIS folder for .application, .deploy and .manifest.
Port is open on my firewall and router.

In Visual Studio, under Publish, file are generated with the .deploy extension. The update location is http://myurl:37113/SecondMarcheERPClicOnce/

[image]

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: make sure your network firewall or antivirus is not blocking the connection try to disable them both. take a network sniff to see if your request goes out and what's being sent on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Following Jalpa comment, I tested on my PC and the issue was there, caused by my antivirus... Firewall wasn't implied. So even if the error message point on my host, it was a lie!

Too there is a strange behavior here. If I install the apps locally, it will work (no surprise here). After, if I update it, so from my website (which is not recognized by my AV as it is a DynDns) it will show the error in my post. Disabling my AV (NOD32) for 10 minutes, the update will pass without any issue. After that, I reactivate the AV and every other update will pass without any issue even if I don't disable my AV.

Hope it help someone someday!

Comment: I am glad that your issue is resolved. 
I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.
Thanks for your understanding.